# Dart 2.10 and `required` keyword

Tags: flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, dart-null-safety

I'm new to both Dart and Flutter so please bear with me if this is off the mark. But I've exhausted my Googlefu and haven't been able to find an answer.

### Context

I'm running Dart 2.10.4 and Flutter 1.22.5. At this point I'm just cloning a bunch of example apps from Github and running them locally by

- Running `flutter pub get`
- Then hitting Run in Android Studio

I am familiar with package management from other languages and have read the docs about potential differences with Dart, in particular

> pub get uses the versions of dependencies locked in it (pubspec.lock) if possible

"if possible" tells me the `pubspec.lock` file is not always respected. The behavior I'm familiar with is for an error to be raised "if not possible".

I should mention that none of the repos I've cloned is very new. They all have over a year's history but have all had recent updates.

### What happened

In *all* of the projects, doing a `flutter pub get` *alters* `pubspec.lock`. The changes are all upgrading the dependencies to a `nullsafety` version. For example `boolean_selector` went from `1.0.5` to `2.1.0-nullsafety.1`. This confused the hell out of me at first. Digging into the `pubspec.yaml` files of the affected packages revealed that the SDK constraint is indeed satisfiable by my Dart version, e.g. [boolean_selector](https://github.com/dart-lang/boolean_selector/blob/2.1.0-nullsafety.1/pubspec.yaml#L10). These version changes broke all of the codebases because of the `required` keyword.

### Question 1

As I understand it, part of the Null-Safety changes is that the `@required` annotation becomes `required`. It's also my understanding that these changes don't land until Dart 2.12. So what's happening here? Why do packages release `nullsafety` versions for Dart 2.10?

### Question 2

The `pubspec.lock` file is satisfiable by my current Dart version. To use the `boolean_selector` example again. The repo in question locks it to 1.0.5 which has an SDK constraint of `sdk: '>=2.0.0 <3.0.0'`. I'm running Dart 2.10. Everything should be fine. Why does `pub get` forcefully upgrade it to the latest compatible version?

### Question 3

I thought ok maybe `required` is an experimental feature we can turn on for Dart 2.10. I read about NNBD and `dart migrate` and have tried it. It doesn't seem to do anything about `required` and would always error out. I read about `dependency_overrides` to use a newer version of `analyzer`. I'd get the same errors. I'm clearly missing something. If Dart 2.10 is compatible with `required` (as opposed to `@required`), how do I make it so?

Comment: "Why do packages release nullsafety versions for Dart 2.10?". This is just a guess from my side but I think it's mainly the package developers making mistakes. I find that even very popular packages have bugs sometimes. Developers are human after all. I would highly suggest to move your project to the most recent stable Flutter release and update any packages you use also regularly to avoid problems like this